# How to write MYSQL query for user hierarchy relationship?

Tags: php, mysql, join

I have user table.

- id - primary key
- user_id - foreign key (user id)
- name
- username
- email
- password

table relationship

- superadmin

  - admin1

    - manager1

      - salesman1

        - customer1
        - customer2
      - salesman2

        - customer3
        - customer4
    - manager2

      - salesman3

        - customer5
        - customer6
      - salesman4

        - customer7
        - custom8

**[Question]**
When manager logged in then show all users under manager with salesman & customers.

when admin logged in then all managers, salesman & customers will be visible.

this is same for all users. If user have users under him/her, he/she can see all user list.

so I need help to write this type sql query.

I wrote like this -

```
SELECT t1.id, t1.group_id, t1.name AS superadmin, t2.name as admin, t3.name as manager, t4.name as salesman, t5.name as customer FROM users AS t1 LEFT JOIN users AS t2 ON t2.user_id = t1.id LEFT JOIN users AS t3 ON t3.user_id = t2.id LEFT JOIN users AS t4 ON t4.user_id = t3.id LEFT JOIN users AS t5 ON t5.user_id = t4.id where t3.id = 15
```

I want this will hapen dynamically.

Comment: Thats a big topic and its not so easy. User hierarchy system requires a very strong algorithm. I have implemented it on an opensource project, you can download it and check the code http://www.sqcrm.com

Comment: i think you may have to include two more columns(usertype ,parent_id)  for manage hierarchy.

Comment: Also consider getting raw data in query and using PHP to roll through the data to sort it out.

Comment: I've another table called user_group. it has usertype. parent_id is user_id

Answer (score 0):

You can add a column `role` in the user table. Then, assuming you keep all the data for the logged user in a `SESSION` you can

`SELECT * FROM users WHERE role < '$_SESSION[role]' AND .....`

Additionally, you can have parent role to use further hierarchy for each role.

Comment: I've separate table for role & I joined it with this table. but I didn't get child users value.